# How to remove 'Object has no method 'forEach' error in node.js'?

Tags: javascript, node.js

My code is as follows:-

```
var generateTypos = function(keywords, options) {
 // Adding a function to the String Prototype that allows to
// change characters at a certain index.
// Needed, since "string"[n] is read-only
String.prototype.replaceAt=function(index, char) {
return this.substr(0, index) + char + this.substr(index+char.length);
};
// Basically a JS Implementation of
// http://web-professor.net/scripts/typo/cTypoGenerator.txt
var keyboard = {"1":["2","q"],"2":["1","q","w","3"],"3":["2","w","e","4"],"4":  ["3","e","r","5"],"5":["4","r","t","6"],"6":["5","t","y","7"],"7":["6","y","u","8"],"8":["7","u","i","9"],"9":["8","i","o","0"],"0":["9","o","p","-"],"-":["0","p"],"q":["1","2","w","a"],"w":["q","a","s","e","3","2"],"e":["w","s","d","r","4","3"],"r":["e","d","f","t","5","4"],"t":["r","f","g","y","6","5"],"y":["t","g","h","u","7","6"],"u":["y","h","j","i","8","7"],"i":["u","j","k","o","9","8"],"o":["i","k","l","p","0","9"],"p":["o","l","-","0"],"a":["z","s","w","q"],"s":["a","z","x","d","e","w"],"d":["s","x","c","f","r","e"],"f":["d","c","v","g","t","r"],"g":["f","v","b","h","y","t"],"h":["g","b","n","j","u","y"],"j":["h","n","m","k","i","u"],"k":["j","m","l","o","i"],"l":["k","p","o"],"z":["x","s","a"],"x":["z","c","d","s"],"c":["x","v","f","d"],"v":["c","b","g","f"],"b":["v","n","h","g"],"n":["b","m","j","h"],"m":["n","k","j"]},
typos = [];
// Generate a homophone object
function getHomophones() {
// German + English Homophones
var homophones = ["Aale, Ahle","Ai, Ei","Annalen, analen","aß, Aas","Bad, bat","bald, ballt","Bällen, bellen","Band, bannt","Beete, bete","bis, Biss","Block, Blog","Boot, bot","Boote, Bote","Bug, buk","Bund, bunt","Chor, Korps","Code, Kot","das, dass","dehnen, denen","erhält, erhellt","Fähre, faire","Fälle, Felle","fällt, Feld","Färse, Ferse, Verse","fast, fasst","fetter, Vetter","fiel, viel","fließt, fliehst, fliest","frisst, Frist","Fühler, Phyla","Geld, gellt","Gewand, gewandt","Grad, Grat","Graf, Graph","Halt, hallt","hallte, halte","hält, Held, hellt","Hämmer, Hemmer","hängst, Hengst","harrt, hart","hasst, hast","Häute, heute","Heer, hehr, her","Hemd, hemmt","hohl, hol","Hund, Hunt","isst, ist","kannte, Kante","konnten, Konten","Kuh, Coup","küsste, Küste","Laib, Leib","Laie, Leihe","laichen, Leichen","lasst, Last","läuten, Leuten","Lärche, Lerche","Leere, Lehre","leeren, lehren","Leerstelle, Lehrstelle","Leid, leiht","Lid, Lied","lies, ließ","liest, least","Mahl, Mal","Mähre, Märe, Meere","mahlen, malen","man, Mann","Märkte, merkte","Meer, mehr","Miene, Mine","misst, Mist","Mohr, Moor","mühten, Mythen","Mund, Munt","Nachnahme, Nachname","nahmen, Namen","packt, Pakt","pisste, Piste","rächen, Rechen","rächt, Recht","Rad, Rat","Rain, rein","Rede, Reede","Reis, reiß","reist, reißt","ruhte, Rute, Route","säen, sähen","Sämann, Seemann","Sätzen, setzen","Saite, Seite","seid, seit","schafft, Schaft","schallten, schalten","Schänke, schenke","schellte, Schelte","Schlächter, schlechter","Schlämme, schlemme","Schwälle, Schwelle","Schwämme, Schwemme","Seen, sehen","seid, seiht, seit","sie, sieh","Siegel, Sigel","Sohle, Sole","Sold, sollt","späht, spät","Stadt, statt","Städte, Stätte","Ställe, Stelle","starrt, Start","stehlen, Stelen","stiehl, Stiel, Stil","Tod, tot","Trend, trennt","Uhrzeit, Urzeit","Verband, verbannt","Verben, werben","verließ, Verlies","verwaist, verweist","Villen, Willen","Waage, vage","Waagen, wagen","Wahl, Wal","wahr, war","wahre, Ware","Waise, Weise","Wald, wallt","Wälle, Welle","Wände, Wende","Weck, weg","Wehr, wer","wehrt, Wert","weiht, weit","weis, weiß","weist, weißt","wieder, wider","wird, Wirt","Zunahme, Zuname","accept,except","acclamation,acclimation","acts,ax,axe","adolescence,adolescents","aeration,erration","aerie,airy","affect,effect","aid,aide","ail,ale","air,heir,err,ere","aisle,isle,I'll","all,awl","allowed,aloud","allude,elude","altar,alter","appose,oppose","arc,ark","are,our","ascent,assent","ate,eight","away,aweigh","aye,I,eye","bade,bayed","bail,bale","bait,bate","bald,bawled,balled","ball,bawl","band,banned","bard,barred","bare,bear","baron,barren","base,bass","based,baste","bazaar,bizarre","be,bee","beach,beech","bean,been","beat,beet","been,bin","beer,bier","bell,belle","berry,bury","berth,birth","better,bettor","bight,bite","billed,build","bird,burred","blew,blue","boar,bore,boor","board,bored","boarder,border","bode,bowed","bold,bowled","bolder,boulder,bowlder","bole,bowl","boos,booze","bough,bow","boy,buoy","braid,brayed","braise,braze,brays,braize","brake,break","breach,breech","bread,bred","brewed,brood","brews,bruise","bridal,bridle","burro,burrow","bus,buss","bused,bust","but,butt","buy,bye,by","cache,cash","callous,callus","can't,cant","cannon,canon","canter,cantor","carat,carrot,caret","caries,carries","cast,caste","cede,seed","cell,sell","cellar,seller","censor,sensor","cent,sent,scent","cents,sense,scents","cereal,serial","cession,session","chaise,chase","chalk,chock","chance,chants","chased,chaste","cheap,cheep","chews,choose","chic,sheik","choir,quire","chord,cored,cord","chute,shoot","cite,site,sight","clause,claws","click,clique","close,clothes","coal,cole","coaled,cold","coarse,course","coated,coded","cocks,cox","complement,compliment","contingence,contingents","coo,coup","coop,coupe","correspondence,correspondents","cosign,cosine","council,counsel","councilor,counselor","creak,creek","crewed,crude","crews,cruise","cue,queue","currant,current","curser,cursor","dam,damn","Dane,deign","days,daze","dear,deer","dense,dents","dependence,dependents","dew,due,do","die,dye","dire,dyer","discreet,discrete","doe,dough","does,doze,doughs","done,dun","dual,duel","ducked,duct","earn,urn","either,ether","emigrant,immigrant","eutopia,utopia","ewe,you,yew","eyed,I'd","fain,feign","faint,feint","fair,fare","fairy,ferry","fate,fete","faze,phase","feat,feet","feudal,futile","find,fined","finish,Finnish","fir,fur","flair,flare","flea,flee","flecks,flex","flew,flue","flour,flower","foaled,fold","for,four,fore","forego,forgo","foreword,forward","forth,fourth","foul,fowl","frees,frieze,freeze","friar,fryer","gage,gauge","gait,gate","gel,jell","gene,jean","gild,guild","gneiss,nice","gored,gourd","grade,grayed,greyed","grate,great","grays,greys,graze","grisly,grizzly","groan,grown","guessed,guest","guide,guyed","guise,guys","hail,hale","hair,hare","hairy,harry","hall,haul","halve,have","hangar,hanger","hay,hey","hays,haze","he'd,heed","he'll,heel,heal","hear,here","heard,herd","heated,heeded","hew,hue","hi,high","higher,hire","him,hymn","ho,hoe","hoar,whore","hoard,horde","hoarse,horse","hoes,hose","hold,holed","hole,whole","holey,wholly,holy","hostel,hostile","hour,our","idle,idol","immanent,imminent","in,inn","incidence,incidents","incite,insight","instance,instants","intense,intents","intension,intention","it's,its","jam,jamb","knave,nave","knead,need,kneed","knew,new","knight,night","knit,nit","knot,not,naught","know,no","knows,nose","lacks,lax","lade,laid","lain,lane","lair,layer","lam,lamb","laps,lapse","lay,lei","lays,laze","leach,leech","lead,led","leak,leek","lean,lien","leased,least","lends,lens","lessen,lesson","lesser,lessor","let's,lets","levee,levy","liar,lyre","lichen,liken","lickerish,licorice","lie,lye","links,lynx","lo,low","load,lode","loan,lone","loch,lock","locks,lox","loop,loupe","loos,lose","lose,loose","made,maid","mail,male","main,mane","maize,maze,Mays","mall,maul","manner,manor","marshal,martial","massed,mast","mat,matte","mean,mien","meat,mete,meet","medal,mettle,meddle,metal","might,mite","mince,mints","mind,mined","miner,minor","missed,mist","moat,mote","mood,mooed","moor,more","morning,mourning","muscle,mussel","mussed,must","naval,navel","nay,neigh","nicks,nix","none,nun","oar,ore,or","ode,owed","oh,owe","once,wants","one,won","oohs,ooze","overseas,oversees","paced,paste","packed,pact","pail,pale","pain,pane","pair,pear,pare","palate,pallet,palette","parish,perish","passed,past","patience,patients","pause,paws","peace,piece","peak,pique,peek","peal,peel","pearl,purl","pedal,petal,peddle","peer,pier","penance,pennants","per,purr","pi,pie","plain,plane","plainer,planer,planar","plait,plate","pleas,please","pole,poll","poor,pour,pore","populace,populous","praise,preys,prays","pray,prey","precedence,precedents","premier,premiere","presence,presents","pride,pried","prier,prior","pries,prize","prince,prints","principal,principle","profit,prophet","rack,wrack","raid,rayed","rail,rale","rain,rein,reign","raise,raze,rays","rap,wrap","rapt,wrapped,wrapt","re-cover,recover","re-lay,relay","read,red","read,reed","real,reel","recede,reseed","reek,wreak","residence,residents","rest,wrest","retch,wretch","rhyme,rime","right,write,rite,wright","ring,wring","ringer,wringer","rise,ryes","road,rowed,rode","roe,row","roil,royal","role,roll","roomer,rumor,rumour","root,route","rose,rows","rote,wrote","rude,rued","rues,ruse","rung,wrung","rye,wry","sail,sale","scene,seen","sea,see","seam,seem","sear,seer","seas,seize,sees","sects,sex","sew,sow,so","shake,sheik","shear,sheer","shoe,shoo","sic,sick","sics,six","side,sighed","sighs,size","sign,sine","slay,sleigh","sleight,slight","slew,slough","soar,sore","soared,sword","sold,soled","sole,soul","some,sum","son,sun","stair,stare","stake,steak","steal,steel","step,steppe","storey,story","straight,strait","suite,sweet","tacked,tact","tacks,tax","tail,tale","taper,tapir","tarry,terry","taught,taut","tea,tee","team,teem","tears,tiers","teas,tees,tease","tense,tents","than,then","there,they're,their","threw,through","throne,thrown","thyme,time","tide,tied","tier,tire","tighten,titan","to,two,too","toad,towed,toed","toe,tow","told,tolled","tracked,tract","tray,trey","udder,utter","vain,vein,vane","vale,veil","vial,vile","vice,vise","wade,weighed","wail,whale","waist,waste","wait,weight","waive,wave","waiver,waver","wale,whale","war,wore","ward,warred","ware,where,wear","warn,worn","wax,whacks","way,whey,weigh","we,wee","we'd,weed","we'll,wheel,weal,wheal","we're,weir,were","we're,whir","we've,weave","weak,week","wearer,where're","weather,whether","wet,whet","wheeled,wield","which,witch","while,wile","whiled,wild","whine,wine","whined,wined,wind","whirled,world","whit,wit","whither,wither","who's,whose","whoa,woe","wood,would","yack,yak","yaw,your,yore,you're","yoke,yolk","yore,your,you're","you'll,Yule","aahed,odd","adieu,ado","ant,aunt","aural,oral","marry,merry","rout,route","seated,seeded","shone,shown","tidal,title","trader,traitor","vary and very"];
var word_sets = homophones.map(function(x) {
return x.toLocaleLowerCase().trim().split(',');
}),
dictionary = {};
word_sets.forEach(function(set) {
set.forEach(function(word) {
dictionary[word] = set;
});
});

return dictionary;
}

// Generate wrong key typos
function wrongKeyTypos(word) {
var word = word.toLocaleLowerCase(),
typos = [],
length = word.length;

for(var i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
if(keyboard[word[i]]) {
var tempWord = word;
keyboard[word[i]].forEach(function(character) {
typos.push(tempWord.replaceAt(i, character).trim());
});
}
}

return typos;
}

// generate missed character typos
function missedCharsTypos(word) {
var word = word.toLocaleLowerCase(),
typos = [],
length = word.length;

for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
var tempWord = '';
if(i === 0) {
tempWord = word.substring(i + 1);
}
else if((i + 1) === length) {
tempWord = word.substring(0, i);
}
else {
tempWord = word.substring(0, i);
tempWord += word.substring(i + 1);
}

typos.push(tempWord);

}

return typos;
}

// generate transposed character typos
function transposedCharTypos(word) {
var word = word.toLocaleLowerCase(),
typos = [],
length = word.length;

for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
if((i + 1) !== length) {
var tempWord = word,
tempChar = tempWord[i];
tempWord = tempWord.replaceAt(i, tempWord[i + 1]);
tempWord = tempWord.replaceAt((i + 1), tempChar);
typos.push(tempWord);
}
}

return typos;
}

// generate double character typos
  function doubleCharTypos(word) {
  var word = word.toLocaleLowerCase(),
  typos = [],
  length = word.length;

  for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  var tempWord = word.substring(0, (i + 1));
  tempWord += word[i];

  if(i !== (length - 1)) {
  tempWord += word.substring(i + 1);
 }
 typos.push(tempWord);
 }

 return typos;
 }

  // Get bit-squatting typos
  // Inspired by http://www.morningstarsecurity.com/research/urlcrazy
  function bitflipping(word) {
   var characters = word.split(''),
  masks = [128,64,32,16,8,4,2,1],
  allowed_chars = /[a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]/,
  typos = [];

 for(var i = 0; i < characters.length; i++) {
 var c = characters[i],
 flipped = masks.map(function(mask) {
 return String.fromCharCode(c.charCodeAt(0) ^ mask).toLocaleLowerCase();
 }).filter(function(x) {
 return x.match(allowed_chars);
 });
  typos.push(flipped.map(function(x) {
 var e = word;
 return e.replaceAt(i, x);
 }));
  }

 return typos.reduce(function(a, b) {
 return a.concat(b);
 },'');
 }

 // Genereate Homephone Typos
  function homophoneTypos(word) {
  var homophones = getHomophones(),
  word = word.toLocaleLowerCase(),
  typos = [];

   for(var key in homophones) {
  if(word.indexOf(key) !== -1) { 
  homophones[key].forEach(function(homophone) {
  if(word.replace(new RegExp(key, "g"), homophone).replace(/ /g, '') !== word) {
 typos.push(word.replace(new RegExp(key, "g"), homophone).replace(/ /g, ''));
   }
   });
  }
}

  return typos;
  }

   keywords.forEach(function(keyword) {
   if(options.wrongKeys) {
   typos.push(wrongKeyTypos(keyword));
 }
 if(options.missedChars) {
 typos.push(missedCharsTypos(keyword));
 }
 if(options.transposedChars) {
 typos.push(transposedCharTypos(keyword));
 }
  if(options.doubleChars) {
 typos.push(doubleCharTypos(keyword));
 }
 if(options.flipBits) {
   typos.push(bitflipping(keyword));
 }
    if(options.generateHomophones) {
   typos.push(homophoneTypos(keyword));
  }
 });

  // Flatten the array of typos
  return typos.reduce(function(a, b) {
   return a.concat(b);
  }, '');
  };

  var input = process.argv, 
  keywords = input.splice(2);

  var typos = generateTypos(keywords, {
  wrongKeys: true,
  missedChars: true,
  transposedChars: true,
  doubleChars: true,
  flipBits: true,
  generateHomophones: true
  });
 typos.forEach(function(typo) {
 console.log(typo);
 });
```

new to javascript and node.js, please help me.

```
 Whenever I try to run the program I receive an error
 node.js:201
    throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
          ^
 TypeError: Object  has no method 'forEach'
 at Object.<anonymous> (/home/chiranjit/Downloads/node-v0.10.20/typos.js:248:7)
 at Module._compile (module.js:441:26)
 at Object..js (module.js:459:10)
 at Module.load (module.js:348:32)
 at Function._load (module.js:308:12)
 at Array.0 (module.js:479:10)
 at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:192:41)
```

I do not understand where is the error. Please help me with the following. How to get rid of TypeError: Object has no method 'forEach'. Also placed '' after the reduce functions as suggested. But then it throws the above error.

Comment: "`Reduce of empty array with no initial value`" seems pretty clear-cut to me. Your line `return typos.reduce(...)` is operating on an empty `typos` array. If you can identify a default "empty" value you expect to come out of that `reduce` call, you can specify it as the second argument to `reduce`. See also MDN's page on [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

Comment: Hello@apsillers please be more specific on how to get rid of the error if possible, new to node.js, used to programming in java, need to know the right answer. any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, if you look at the stack trace you can see that the offending code is on line 194 in typos.js (which is line 196 in the file you have linked to). `Array.reduce` fails with a `TypeError` if the array is empty and there is no initial value specified. Providing an initiual value should help:

```
return typos.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a.concat(b);
}, '');
```

Replace `''` with the correct initial value, if needed.

Comment: sorry could not follow it properly, as mentioned this is basic, but I am new to node.js, if possible please specify the solution to the problem, it will be of great help to me.

Comment: @user2602860 it's right there in the answer, you need to replace your code at line 196 with the code in my answer

Comment: do I have to basically replace all typos with some string value ? i.e typos=[] will become typos=[hello] for example.

Comment: sorry but it is still throwing the same error.I basically replaced with the above code. I use node typos.js to run the program.I appreciate your help.

Comment: it solved the previous issue, now what about the new error? please point out the error. Gone through some material to understand but to no avail.